Canonical form of presentation matrix
Setup: We know that an $R$-module $M$ is finally presented if it is isomorphic to $R^m/AR^n$, where $A$ is an $m$-by-$n$ matrix known as the presentation matrix. Determining $A$ amounts to picking a set of $m$ generators of $M$, which determines a homomorphism $\phi: R^m \rightarrow M$, and then picking a set of $n$ generators for $\ker(\phi)$.
Next, we may perform various procedures to simplify $A$. We can change basis to put $A$ into Smith normal form. We may then remove any columns that are all $0$, and we can also remove the row and column associated with any diagonal entry that is a unit.
Question: after conducting this procedure, do we always end up with the same canonical presentation matrix (up to units) regardless of how we originally chose the generators? If $M$ is an abelian group, I think this amounts to the uniqueness of the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, so I am hopeful that this works in general.

The answer is yes, after conducting the procedure to transform the presentation matrix A into its SNF and removing zero columns and unit entries, we always end up with the same canonical presentation of matrix. This ensure the uniqueness of SNF and aligns with the fundamental theorem of finitely generated modules over PID, which includes the case of finite abelian group.
